# how to understand "interchange of filtering with compressor/expander"

Tags: signal-processing

In Sec. 4.7 of the classical textbook "Discrete-Time Signal Processing (3rd)", the efficient implementation of multi-rate processing is well discussed. The first method deal with the "interchange of filtering with compressor/expander", and the following figure shows the interchange in downsampling. [image: Fig. 4.31 Two equivalent systems based on downsampling identities]

Since downsampling can cause aliasing, the pre-filtering is necessary. In the figure, we can notice that H(z) in (a) and H(z^M) in (b); however, if aliasing has occurred after downsampling in (a), can H(z) eliminates the aliasing? Thank you!

Comment: I think this question would fit best http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the original filter was of the form `H(z^M)`, meaning that only every `M`th coefficient of the filter is non-zero.

The reason this is possible comes down to the fact that only each `M`th input sample actually factors into the output sequence in this configuration.  It is a special case since input samples at non multiples of `M` are always cancelled out by either the filter zero coefficients or the decimator.  It is unnecessary to even consider input samples at indexes other than multiples of `M`.

This means you can decimate the input first and then apply the filter with its zero coefficients removed.

Comment: It seems that the filters in the figure are not the low-pass filters used in decimation?

Comment: Yeah, you would usually have to convert a standard filter to its polyphase representation, which would result in a bank of filters that each have the form `H(z^M)` and are equivalent to the original filter when applied correctly in a filter bank.  Usually the Noble identity you posted is used as a building block for larger efficient filter bank structures, and not just used on its own for downsampling.  If you are just downsampling, you probably need to apply the filter before the decimator and use a standard low pass antialiasing filter.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. The contents are for the following polyphase processing.